# How to decrease brightness even more in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, brightness

I have been using an app called DimScreen on Windows, but I can't find any app that would make it possible for my Ubuntu. I tried xbacklight and it does not seem to work.

Do you guys know how to decrease it lower than the minimum brightness?

Comment: You could try `redshift`.  GNOME found on 18.04 has it's own 'night light' facilities, which is the primary purpose of redshift, but redshift lets you configure a number of settings like brightness= and may achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

**dconf approach**

There are many options. But I am quite satisfied with using setting brightness value in dconf – this is a Ubuntu alternative to windows registry.

1. First, you have to enable Zoom options in settings / Universal access / Zoom / [image: enable button]
2. Then install a nice tool to manipulate dconf and run it:

`sudo apt install dconf-editor
dconf-editor # this can be done from your start menu too`

3. Find `/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier` folder (either by clicking through the tree or by hitting Ctrl+f and typing "magnif".
4. Tweak brightness-red/green/blue values
5. Or launch these commands to reduce the brightness programatically:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-red -0.6
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-green -0.6
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier brightness-blue -0.6`

**/sys/class approach**

If you are not happy with enabling Zoom, you may try to edit `brightness` file in a `backlight` folder. At my computer, I find it on `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

1. I check current brightness level:

`$cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
400`

2. I set the file to be editable:

`sudo chmod o+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

3. I decrease the brightness to 100:

`echo "100" > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

The lowest level seems to be "1", if I try to put "0" or invalid input, write permisssion is denied.

**xrandr approach**

`xrandr` is a great tool to handle display properties. First run it without parameters to check out your monitor names. Ex: my monitor name is `eDP-1`

```bsh
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5208 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1368x768+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
```

Now you can put a float number to the brightness property (software only modification):

```bsh
$xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
```

As of Ubuntu 18.10, it seems I could combine all three approaches independently.

Comment: Thanks, enabling the zoom and decreasing the brightness in the colour panel did the trick. But enabling zoom noticeably made my cursor lag :/

Comment: Hi, I've added another solution that doesn't need Zoom enabled. Does this works better for you?

Comment: Hi, 1 is the normal minimum brightness, I want to be able to go below the normal minimum one. But yeah error when I try to go lower than that. Appreciate your response tho;)

Comment: Try the third solution I've added. I really need your points :D

Comment: Option 1: Was too much work so I did not test it (Since someone already said they tried it and it's the same as setting the brightness normally)

Comment: Option 2: Same as Option 1. I wanted to make sure I could reset. So I went to the directory and found a `max_brightness` and a `min_brightness` of `100` and `1`. My `brightness` file was at `2`. Can't get it too much lower than that :( I have AMD so it might be different.

Comment: Option 3: This worked, but I checked the man pages just in case. the brightness value is a multiplier, and you can't "get" it, you can only edit it. It resets after restart. But there's a big problem, if you bring it down past a certain limit (not sure how to check the exact number) it completely decomposes your computers colors. Just shifts it all up. Looks like whatever values are being multiplied, they are either really small, really big, or not floating points, or maybe a combination. **TL;DR** You should not edit brightness below minimum with this option, there are too many values to edit